# how to get a value from an escaping closure and assign it to a variable and display in tableview

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, closures, core-location

I calculated the distance using CoreLocation, but I couldn't assign the distance to a variable and display the value in Tableview.

I used forwardGeocoding function to convert String to CLLocation type and got the distance between two spots. And I can print the data within the closure but I can never assign the distance to a variable out of the closure.

```
// This function will accept a string and convert to CLLocation
func forwardGeocoding(address:String, completion: @escaping ((CLLocation?) -> Void))
{
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
        if let error = error
        {
            print(error)
            completion(nil)
        }
        else
        {
            // found locations, then perform the next task using closure
            let placemark = placemarks?[0]
            completion(placemark?.location) // execute closure
        }
    })
}

// This function will find the distance, assign it to a local variable and return it 
func searchDistance(_ address: String) -> Double
{
    var distance: Double = 0
    self.forwardGeocoding(address:address, completion: {(location) in
        if let locationTo = location {
            // calculate distance
            distance = (self.mainDelegate.currLocation?.distance(from: locationTo))!
            // distance has value here
            print("distance in closure \(distance)")

        } else {
            // not found destination, show alert
            print("cannot find address")
        }
    })
    print(distance) // fails to catch the distance, always 0
    return distance      
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let tableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DonorCell", for: indexPath) as? DonorListTableViewCell ?? DonorListTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "DonorCell")

    let index = indexPath.row
    tableCell.donorName?.text = donors[index].organizationName
    tableCell.donorAddress?.text = "\(donors[index].street ?? ""), \( donors[index].city ?? "")"
    tableCell.donorPhone?.text = donors[index].phoneNumber

    let donorAddress = "\(donors[index].street ?? "") \(donors[index].city ?? "") \(donors[index].postalCode ?? "")"

    // This is always 0
    let distanceOnMap = searchDistance(donorAddress)

    return tableCell
}
```

I assume it's the @escaping problem, but I don't know how to modify it to display the distance in table cell successfully. Please help

Comment: Your code can never work. `forwardGeocoding` does geocoding _asynchronously_. `searchDistance` gets back a value in its completion handler _asynchronously_. All of that happens long after you've returned the cell for the table view in `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to modify to display the distance on the tableview then?

Comment: Yes, your completion handler modifies the data model and reloads the table view. This is exactly like getting images over the network for use in a table view’s cells. This topic has been thoroughly explained here already.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was solved under my teacher's help.
The solution is creating an instance variable, then calling self.tableview.reload directly in the closure. In the tableView cellForRowAT, just loading the value from instance variable.

```
func searchAddress(_ address: String)
{
    self.forwardGeocoding(address:address, completion: {(location) in
        if let locationTo = location {
            // calculate distance
            self.donorDistance.append((self.mainDelegate.currLocation?.distance(from: locationTo) ?? 0))
            print(self.mainDelegate.currLocation?.distance(from: locationTo) ?? 0)
            if self.donorDistance.count == self.donors.count
            {
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }              
        } else {
            // not found destination, show alert
            print("cannot find address")
        }
    })
}
```